# How to save an array of type MKMapItem

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, nsuserdefaults

How can I save and retrieve an array of `MKMapItem`s with the help of `UserDefaults`?

```
var recentDestination: [MKMapItem] = []
```

Comment: [`MKMapItem`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapitem) conforms to [`NSSecureCoding`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nssecurecoding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `MKMapItem` conforms to `NSCoding`, you can **save** the `[MKMapItem]` in the form of `Data` in `UserDefaults` using `NSKeyedArchiver`, i.e.

```
let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: recentDestination)
UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "recentDestination")
```

Similary, to **fetch** the saved data from `UserDefaults` use `NSKeyedUnarchiver` like so,

```
if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "recentDestination") {
    if let arr = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? [MKMapItem] {
        print(arr)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UserDefaults should not be used for storing data bigger then numbers/strings/bools. For this purpose you should use NSKeyArchiver